# How can i split values in different arrays?

Tags: java, android

I am doing a project in android ,and i have a problem My array list values like this

```
[men-1, men-2, men-3, women-1, women-2, women-3]
```

How can I split these values in different arrays? i.e how can I save `men-1,men-2,men-3` in one array and `women-1,women-2,women-3` in other array?

Comment: Are your elements Strings or some objects of Man, Woman classes?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to help you without details but you should probably

1. create separate Lists for man and woman elements,
2. iterate over all elements of your lists

   1. in case of list is string you can determine its gender using `element.startsWith("man")`
   2. in case elements are objects of Man or Woman classes you can use `instanceof` operator like `if (element instanceof Man){listOfMans.add(element)}`
3. now if you want to place ell elements in separate arrays you can use `toArray(T[] array)` method from each `List` instance.

Answer (score 0):

the below code may help you

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String[] input = new String[] {"men-1", "men-2", "men-3", "women-1", "women-2", "women-3"};
       int arr1Size=getCount(input, "women");
       String[] arr1 = new String[arr1Size];
       String[] arr2 = new String[input.length-arr1Size];
       int i=0,j=0;
       for(String str: input){
           if(str.contains("women")){
               arr1[i] = str;
               i++;
           }else{
               arr2[j] = str;
               j++;
           }           
       }
       System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr1));
       System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr2));       
    }

    public static int getCount(String[] input, String find){
        int count=0;
        for(String str: input){
           if(str.contains(find)){
               count++;
           }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If those are the object of a class then you can easily do it using instanceOf operator... Otherwise below code can help you.. you can do it using arrays only as well as using arraylist

```
   /**
 * 
 */
package com.sharique.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Sharique
 *
 */
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    //List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    //int[] arr = new int[10];
    //int[] ar1= arr.clone();

    public void usingArrays(){
        StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer("Men");
        String[] arrays = {"Men-1","Men-2","Men-3","Women-1","Women-2","Women-3"};
        String[] arrOfMen = new String[3];
        String[] arrOfWomen = new String[3];
        String str=null;
        int count1=0;
        int count2=0;
        for(int i=0;i<arrays.length;i++){
            str=arrays[i];
            if(str.contains(sb1)){
                arrOfMen[count1++]=str;
            }else{              
                arrOfWomen[count2++]=str;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<arrOfMen.length;i++)
            System.out.print(arrOfMen[i]+" ");
        //For a new Line
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<arrOfWomen.length;i++)
            System.out.print(arrOfWomen[i]+" ");
    }
    public void usingArrayList(){
        String[] arrays1 = {"Men-1","Men-2","Men-3","Women-1","Women-2","Women-3"};
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arrays1));
        String[] arrays2 = new String[3];
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Women");
        int count=0;
        String str=null;
        Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            str =iterator.next();
            if(str.contains(sb)){
                arrays2[count++] = str;
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
        //for a new line
        System.out.println();
        arrays1 = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        for(int i=0;i<arrays1.length;i++)
            System.out.print(arrays1[i]+" ");
        //for a new line
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<arrays2.length;i++)
            System.out.print(arrays2[i]+" ");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Test test = new Test();
        test.usingArrays();
        test.usingArrayList();

    }

}
```